# How to hide validatorMessage when field is empty

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Please help how to hide validatorMessage when user clearing the field:

```
 <div class="item">
    <p:outputLabel for="firstName" value="#{msgs['customerForm.firstName']}"/>
    <p:inputText id="firstName" value="#{customerBean.customer.firstName}"
    requiredMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.mandatory']}"
    validatorMessage="#{msgs['Error.firstName.wrongFormat']}"required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*){1,255}$" />
    </p:inputText>
    <p:message id="m_firstName" for="firstName" display="text"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the technology you are using for the UI? Is it JSP? AngularJS? I am not actually quite sure what this code has to do with Java at all...

Comment: it's most probably primefaces

Comment: But it should display the message when field is empty, because field is `required` - that's precisely the point.

Comment: u try defining <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="m_firstName" /> in input

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: Yes, but if you look correctly (and read the Q again) you'll notice that there is a second (regex) validatior AND that the OP wants to remove a (visible) validation error when the field is cleared. So the 'required' validator is not the issue here.

Comment: @Kukeltje, ah, now I see. He defined regex in a way that does not allow empty values. His internal implementation sees two problems with value: it is empty and required, and it does not pass the regex.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works! Can you give me suggestion about using it in Calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your field having two validations:
 * required value validator
 * regular expression validator

Both validators have equivalent priority, and both are run against your field value. And both of these validators see empty value as a problem, and your framework, unable to determine which of these two equivalent-looking failures is the "actual" failure, displays both.

To "fix" it, you should allow empty values to pass your regex, like this:

```
      <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z\s\-]*){0,255}$" />
```

Notice that I changed number qualifier to allow 0-255 characters instead of 1-255 characters like before.
That should allow two of your validators cover different cases of invalid values, like you intended.

Comment: its works <f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="m_firstName" />

Comment: but what should i do in calendar?

Comment: @DmitriyLaletin, it is very unlikely that it works the same as that configuration you've posted, because these do different things. It can **appear** that they work similarly, but in the end they do not.

Comment: @DmitriyLaletin, as for calendar, I don't really understand what you mean. I suggest you ask another question for that, or maybe update this one if it is similar enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729481/clean-err-messages-dynamicaly-when-user-cleared-input-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can update the error messages if you put this in the input element. It will validate the input on every keyup event though.

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" event="keyup" render="m_firstName" />
```

Comment: maybe you can open another thread for the calendar thing @Dmitriy Laletin

Comment: Thanks! Give me please another help - now I need change code -so i have to show err messages when user press save button (end part of my xhtml) and dinamic hide err message if input field is cleared

Comment: why don't you accept this answer and open up a new question and we'll look into that too. We shouldn't go beyond the scope of this question. you can paste the url to your new question here.

Comment: I got limit to questions and untill tomorrow i cant open new question